# Using php include to add second/third/forth file from a folder?

Tags: php, include

This is a 2 part question from a NOVICE so if the answer could be explained carefully that would be appreciated.

Currently I'm using this code to add the latest News Article to my front page from the News folder, each article is a separate html page.

```
    <?php $files = glob('news/*.html'); 
sort($files);    
$newest = array_pop($files); 
    include($newest); ?>
```

But how would I go about adding the second, the third, the forth and so on file from said folder without adding all of them.

Now the second question, How do i create an "echo" function the same way to link to these articles. currently I use this simple method   `<a href="#20130207 Grass Lands"> Grass Lands</a>`   but i have to manualy do it every time a new article comes. I thought of using this. (NOTE all the news html pages are named "20130207 Grass Lands.html" , "20130206 Demons vs Fairyland" and so on.)

```
    <a href="# <?php $files = glob('news/*.html'); 
sort($files);    
$newest = array_pop($files); 
    echo $newest; ?>  "> <?php $files = glob('news/*.html'); 
sort($files);    
$newest = array_pop($files); 
    echo $newest; ?>
    </a>
```

but the button ends up reading "news/20130207 Grass Lands.html" how do I cut out the "news/20130207" and the ".html" part of the button and just leave the "Grass Lands".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want to generate static pages and still have the minimum functionality of a `CMS`;

The first thing you have to do is create a rule for naming the urls/files; this has to be unique;

like: `number-varchar1-varchar2-varchar3.html`

the number needs to be incremented each time, not a random number!

now, every time you need to list the articles/pages you can do it in 2 ways:

a. load all the articles from a statis page that you created/refreshed with new data each time you added new news

b. load the files from that folder using a scan method

now, sort the links, using `explode()` method, by using the `-` as key; sort them by the number, descending, because you want the new news to be on top

but i have some questions:

1. how will you edit the news? will you edit the files manually?
2. you need htaccess skills to use seo friendly urls? do you know how htaccess rules work?
3. why dont you use `wordpress` of `yii framework` ?

Yii does miracles, I could teach you;

Comment: I'm a graphic artist, I'm not really a site maker so my knowledge is limited, that is also the reason I asked for an explanation. here is my site(news page, PS the site is still a mess) [link](http://www.cube3graphics.com/news.php). Currently I have my news set up so that its posts reverse alphabetically and that works fine, however I would love to know if there was a way to just put the latest 10-20 articles only, ignoring the older ones that would be archived else where.

Comment: I have 2 people that would write these news posts by editing the image, title, and paragraph from a template using Dreamweaver.

Further more on the right side of the news page you will see a box with links to scroll down to the articles is there a way to mkae that box update it self, I can think of a way I'm just not smart enough to figure out how to code it.

And finaly using WordPress, Wix, Weebly, Blooger, or any of those things is out of the question.

If you could help that would be swell.

Comment: use Yii and I will help you to get a working website; the list will not update on its own, and if you dont have the programming skills, dont start the developing process; nobody is going to write new code for you with this website; get a new website, simple, clean, like www.linkbook.ro

Comment: or better, use wordpress, it has everything you need as i see

Comment: and also, we need to keep in touch, as you could help me also with a game of mine that i am developing

Comment: @ Ionut Flavius Pogacian , Iv sent you a msg from your site

Comment: ok, no message has arrived; pls send one from your email to my email; office@linkbook.ro

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the second part of my own dilemma and want to leave the code here for future armatures who want to know how do do this.

```
    <?php   
$files = glob('news/*news.php');
rsort($files);
$before = '<a href="#';
$after = '</div></a>';

foreach ($files as $f) {
    $f = substr($f, 14, -9);
    $link = $before . $f . '"><div>' . $f . $after;
    echo $link;
} ?>
```

all this creates a button that looks like this

```
<a href="#Demons vs Fairyland, another TD game Not as bad as it sounds"><div>Demons vs Fairyland, another TD game Not as bad as it sounds</div></a>
```

Now on the side of my articles I added this code to the top which would create and anchor of the files name

```
<a id="<?php echo substr(basename(__FILE__, ".php"), 9); ?>" name="<?php echo substr(basename(__FILE__, ".php"), 9); ?>"></a>
```

this creates a anchor that will look liek this

```
<a id="Demons vs Fairyland, another TD game Not as bad as it sounds" name="Demons vs Fairyland, another TD game Not as bad as it sounds"></a>
```

It took me days to do this I hope the next guy will just use my code and save him self the torture.

Comment: the a tag is wrong in all 3 solutions; the href must be a valid url; the id must be a unique name like demonsvsfairyland; the name, also unique like anothername; the all need to be set without any white space